# call webservice on anchor tag click event using ajax with parametere change in url 

Tags: php, ajax, anchor

```
<?php


                     $dest=explode(",",$destination);
                     $city= $dest[0];
                     $state= $dest[1];
                     $country= $dest[2];
                    // initiate curl and set options
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    $ver = 'v3/';
                    $method = 'list/';
                    $otherElementsStr = 'cid=55505&minorRev=5&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/4.0&customerIpAddress=172.16.82.13&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD';
                    $apiKey = 'myapikey';  
                    $secret = 'mysecretkey';  
                    $timestamp = gmdate('U'); // 1200603038
                    //echo $timestamp;   
                    $sig = md5($apiKey . $secret . $timestamp);
                    $service = 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/';
                    $filter='&city='.$city.'&stateProvinceCode='.$state.'&countryCode='.$country.'&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED&arrivalDate='.$CheckInDate.'&departureDate='.$CheckOutDate;
                    $url =$service.$ver. $method ."?apiKey=".$apiKey."&sig=".$sig.$otherElementsStr.$filter ;
                    //echo $url;
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
                    $json = curl_exec($ch);
                    if(!$json) {
                        echo curl_error($ch);
                    }
                    curl_close($ch);

                    //print_r(json_decode($json));

                    $array = json_decode($json, true);

                    $hotels = $array['HotelListResponse']['HotelList']['HotelSummary'];
                    $result='';
                    foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {
                        $result .= '<div class="hotel-listing-inner">
                                        <div class="list-hotel-1">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="http://images.travelnow.com/'. $hotel['thumbNailUrl'] . '" alt="" border="0" /></a>
                                            <span><a href="#">more photos</a></span>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="list-hotel-right">
                                        <div class="charge-btn">
                                            <a href="#"><strong>'. number_format((float)$hotel['lowRate'], 2, '.', '') . '</strong>
                                                Per Night</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="select-btn"><a href="#">select hotel</a></div>

                                    </div>    
                                        <div class="listing-content">
                                            <h2><a href="#">' . $hotel['name'] . '</a></h2>
                                            <div class="star-rating">
                                            <span class="stars">'. $hotel['hotelRating'] .'</span>

                                            </div>
                                            <h3>3.5</h3>
                                            <div class="rating-img"><img src="images/guest-reviews-2-5.png" alt="" border="0" />from 197 guest reviews</div>
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="city-name">
                                            <p>' . $hotel['address1'] . ',' . $hotel['postalCode'] . '</p>
                                            <p>' . $hotel['city'] . ','. $hotel['countryCode'] . '</p>
                                            <p><a href="#">Show on Map or Get Directions</a></p>
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="hotel-locat">
                                        <span>
                                         ' . html_entity_decode($hotel['shortDescription'] ). '
                                         </span>
                                         <a href="#">more</a>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>';
                    }


                    echo $result;

            ?>
```

this is basically an EAN API Call. Now i have an anchor tag on same page **Sort by Price**  , When user click on that link this web service need to be call again but different filter parameter . some changes will be made to this string.

```
$filter='&city='.$city.'&stateProvinceCode='.$state.'&countryCode='.$country.'&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED&arrivalDate='.$CheckInDate.'&departureDate='.$CheckOutDate;
```

**so my question is how can i call php code again with changes in URL of webservice when an anchor button is clicked .**

Comment: Are you looking to do this using AJAX?

Comment: no need of ajax, just pure server side code.actually i am asp.net with c# , so there we just use asp:linkbutton and use its click event .

Comment: So your anchor will just reload the page with a parameter passed for the filter to be used?

Comment: yes , you can check http://www.hotelsfirst.com/search/?destination=Jaipur%2C+IN&destination-id=F65B6367-AB1B-4C30-9169-E183374A93F6&check-in=mm%2Fdd%2Fyyyy&check-out=mm%2Fdd%2Fyyyy here sort . this is exactly i want to do

Comment: You do realize that is using AJAX right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15286/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-mike-brant)

Comment: @MikeBrant so should i change my question title ?